# Installing an internal website certificate in a domain controller?

Tags: certificate, windows-domain, pki, certificate-authority

The context is a Windows domain. My end goal here is to have an internal website (Website server is domain-joined) show as "trusted" when I visit it from my domain workstation.

Currently (in firefox or Edge for example), the website shows "Connection not secure" but I have installed the site's .cer in the domain controller's Certificate Authority.
I can see it in certsrv under Issued Certificates! (Had to censor most of the content) but I can gaurantee that the:
Serial number, Issued Country/Region, Issued Common Name=Subject Name Common Name, Validity Before and After
all match between this screen below and the certificate I see in a browser

[image]

In the end, this internal website is still showing as insecure.

Comment: Wait, how _did_ you install it on the domain controller? Are you talking about certmgmt.msc, or certlm.msc, or Group Policy? The "Certificate Authority" module isn't a place to install certificates _to_ (rather the opposite)... Was the website's certificate actually issued by your internal CA?

Comment: Ok that would explain part of the problem. I somehow managed to make a request and import the websites certificate into "Certificate Authority". The certificate is self-signed by the web app installer on that internal website... I don't have a certmgmt.msc on my windows server 2022 or 2019

Comment: The "Certification Authority" module is for _creating_ CAs. It would be reasonable to use it to issue internal-CA-signed certificates to internal websites, instead of using self-signed certs everywhere, but it sounds like you did the opposite and turned the website's cert _into_ a CA? Do you have a screenshot of the "Certification Authority" window, and a screenshot of what the actual website's certificate looks like in a web browser?

Comment: I mistyped the name, it's certmgr.msc rather than certmgmt.msc

Comment: "although I can't find the utility where I installed it again." - You can double click the certificate in order to install it.  Where did you install it exactly?  Where within the certificate store did you install it to? Instead of commentary, you should clarify your question by editing it.  "I don't have a `certmgr.msc` on my windows server 2022 or 2019 " - Impossible it has to exist.,

Comment: @user1686 Confirming that certmgr.msc is the one I used yes. I also updated my answer confirming that serial number, effective, expiration all match. I'm now reviewing how I can do this un-backwards like you said. 1. Ill see if I can make a new cert from certmgr.msc and pout that in the website, and 2. also how I should do this using certlm.msc

Comment: @ramhound I've edited my answer to remove the statement where I had added the certificate to mmc.msc -> Certificates snap-in  because the certificate is no longer there. I must have removed it at some point.

Comment: To clarify, certsrv.msc is where you "make" new certificates (i.e. run your own CA), while certmgr.msc/certlm.msc is where you install existing CA certificates to mark them as trusted.

Comment: @bluesquare - you didn’t write an answer your wrote a question and you don’t have to ping users to let them know you modified your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you used the "Certification Authority" module `certsrv.msc`, but that's the wrong place to install website certificates. This module is used for *creating* an internal CA – you could use it to start up a "Bluesquare CA" which could then issue locally-trusted certificates for all your internal websites or webapps – however, it is not the place for *importing* a website's self-signed cert.

The actual console for managing trusted certificates in Windows is `certmgr.msc` for per-user settings and `certlm.msc` for machine-level settings. If you want to make your custom CA (or a self-signed website certificate) recognized by Windows, install it via either certmgr.msc or certlm.msc under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". (Right-click, then use "All tasks → Import".)

Also, certificates are validated by each host individually, not by the domain controller. Even if you use certlm.msc, installing a CA certificate into your DCs still affects only the DCs themselves – the CA is not automatically distributed to member hosts.

You need to use Group Policy in order to distribute custom CA certificates to domain computers (via "Computer Configuration → Policies → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Public Key Policies → Trusted Root Certification Authorities").

---

*(You still shouldn't deploy individual website certificates, though. If the website cannot use a public CA, then create an internal CA (indeed via "Certification Authority") – that way you only need one GPO to deploy one CA certificate, and it can be used to issue certs for any number of internal websites.)*